# Python execute function at child process exit

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a memoization function wrapper with a counter of hits and misses.
Because I can't access none-local variables from the function, I use a dictionary to count the hits and the misses.

The function run in ~1000 parallel processes on 48 cores, over a million times per core, so I am using a `Manager.dict` to manage the score.

Just keeping the score alone triples my execution time, so I wanted to do something smarter - I want to keep a local counter that is just a normal dictionary, and when the process exits, add that score to the general score dictionary which is managed by the manager.

Is there a way to execute a function at the child-process exit? something like `atexit` that works for spawned children.

Relevant code: (Note the `MAGICAL_AT_PROCESS_EXIT_CLASS`, which is what I want)

```
manager = Manager()

global_score = manager.dict({
    "hits": 0,
    "misses": 0
})

def memoize(func):
    local_score = {
        "hits": 0,
        "misses": 0
    }

    cache = {}

    def process_exit_handler():
        global_score["hits"] += local_score["hits"]
        global_score["misses"] += local_score["misses"]

    MAGICAL_AT_PROCESS_EXIT_CLASS.register(process_exit_handler)

    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args):
        cache_key = pickle.dumps(args)
        if cache_key not in cache:
            local_score["misses"] += 1
            cache[cache_key] = func(*args)
        else:
            local_score["hits"] += 1
        return cache[cache_key]

    return wrap


def exit_handler():
    print("Cache", global_score)

atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

(Yes, I am aware it caches every process independently. Yes, that is desired behaviour)

**Current solution:**
This is only relevant to my specific function use case. I run the function once per process, and it spwans itself about a million more times per run.
I changed my wrapper method in the following way:

```
@wraps(func)
def wrap(*args):
    cache_key = pickle.dumps(args)
    if cache_key not in cache:
        local_score["misses"] += 1
        local_score["open"] += 1
        cache[cache_key] = func(*args)
        local_score["open"] -= 1
    else:
        local_score["hits"] += 1

    if local_score["open"] == 0:
        score["hits"] += local_score["hits"]
        score["misses"] += local_score["misses"]
        local_score["hits"] = 0
        local_score["misses"] = 0

    return cache[cache_key]
```

Which instead of synchronized writing a few hundred million times, it only needs to synchronize the number of processes (1000).

Comment: What kind of task is `func` doing? Are you asking for usage with `multiprocessing.Pool` or self spawned processes?

Comment: @Darkonaut I am using `multiprocessing.Pool`. The function is a recursive function, with a depth of 6 on average, and breadth of 10.

Comment: Got it stable. Btw, Am I understanding you right in that you build a Pool with 1000 processes although you have "only" 48 cores? If yes, why is that?

Comment: @Darkonaut Amazing solution! Thanks. And no, I just miswrote. I have a pool size 48, running map on an array with size 1000~

Comment: A possible workaround is to make use of undocumented `multiprocessing.util.Finalize` class, see the blog post for details: [Guaranteed Finalization Without Context Manager](https://zpz.github.io/blog/guaranteed-finalization-without-context-manager/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be relatively easy to realize this with subclassing `Process`, to enhance it with memoization and then building your own pool out of it, but since you want to use `multiprocessing.Pool`, it's getting complicated. `Pool` doesn't enable this by choice, we have to meddle with its guts to make it possible. Make sure no child-process is watching when you proceed reading.

---

There are two problems to solve.

1. Making the child process calling the exit-handler upon process termination.
2. Prevent `Pool` from terminating the child before their exit-handlers finished.

For use with forking as start method for child processes, I found it necessary to monkey patch `multiprocessing.pool.worker`. We could use `atexit` with start method 'spawn' (default on Windows), but this would only spare us little and deprive us from the benefits of forking, hence the following code does not make use of `atexit`. The patch is a wrapper around `worker`, calling our custom `at_exit` function as the worker returns, which happens when the process is about to exit.

```
# at_exit_pool.py

import os
import threading
from functools import wraps
import multiprocessing.pool
from multiprocessing.pool import worker, TERMINATE, Pool
from multiprocessing import util, Barrier
from functools import partial


def finalized(worker):
    """Extend worker function with at_exit call."""
    @wraps(worker)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = worker(*args, **kwargs)
        at_exit()  # <-- patch
        return result
    return wrapper


worker = finalized(worker)
multiprocessing.pool.worker = worker  # patch
```

This solution is also subclassing `Pool` to deal with both problems. `PatientPool` is introducing two mandatory arguments `at_exit` and `at_exit_args`. `at_exit` is taking the exit-handler and `PatientPool` is piggybacking `initializer` from the standard `Pool` to register the exit-handler in the child processes. Here are the functions dealing with registering the exit-handler:

```
# at_exit_pool.py

def at_exit(func=None, barrier=None, *args):
    """Call at_exit function and wait on barrier."""
    func(*args)
    print(os.getpid(), 'barrier waiting')  # DEBUG
    barrier.wait()


def register_at_exit(func, barrier, *args):
    """Register at_exit function."""
    global at_exit
    at_exit = partial(at_exit, func, barrier, *args)


def combi_initializer(at_exit_args, initializer, initargs):
    """Piggyback initializer with register_at_exit."""
    if initializer:
        initializer(*initargs)
    register_at_exit(*at_exit_args)
```

As you can see in `at_exit`, we're going to use a `multiprocessing.Barrier`. Using this synchronization primitive is the solution for our second problem, preventing `Pool` from terminating the child-process before the exit-handler has done it's job.

A Barrier works in a way, that would block any process calling `.wait()` on it as long a 'parties' number of processes has not called `.wait()` on it.

`PatientPool` initializes such a barrier and passes it to its child processes. The `parties` parameter in this barrier is set to the number of child process + 1. The child-processes are calling `.wait()` on this barrier, as soon they complete `at_exit`. `PatientPool` itself also calls `.wait()` on this barrier. This happens within the `_terminate_pool` method we're overriding in `Pool` for this purpose. Doing so prevents the pool from terminating the child-processes too early, since all processes calling `.wait()` will be released only when all child-processes have reached the barrier, also.

```
# at_exit_pool.py

class PatientPool(Pool):
    """Pool class which awaits completion of exit handlers in child processes
    before terminating the processes."""

    def __init__(self, at_exit, at_exit_args=(), processes=None,
                 initializer=None, initargs=(), maxtasksperchild=None,
                 context=None):
        # changed--------------------------------------------------------------
        self._barrier = self._get_barrier(processes)

        at_exit_args = (at_exit, self._barrier) + at_exit_args
        initargs = (at_exit_args, initializer, initargs)

        super().__init__(
            processes, initializer=combi_initializer, initargs=initargs,
            maxtasksperchild=maxtasksperchild, context=context
        )
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    @staticmethod
    def _get_barrier(processes):
        """Get Barrier object for use in _terminate_pool and
        child processes."""
        if processes is None:  # this will be repeated in super().__init__(...)
            processes = os.cpu_count() or 1
        if processes < 1:
            raise ValueError("Number of processes must be at least 1")

        return Barrier(processes + 1)

    def _terminate_pool(self, taskqueue, inqueue, outqueue, pool,
                        worker_handler, task_handler, result_handler, cache):
        """changed from classmethod to normal method"""
        # this is guaranteed to only be called once
        util.debug('finalizing pool')

        worker_handler._state = TERMINATE
        task_handler._state = TERMINATE

        util.debug('helping task handler/workers to finish')
        self.__class__._help_stuff_finish(inqueue, task_handler, len(pool))  # changed

        assert result_handler.is_alive() or len(cache) == 0

        result_handler._state = TERMINATE
        outqueue.put(None)  # sentinel

        # We must wait for the worker handler to exit before terminating
        # workers because we don't want workers to be restarted behind our back.
        util.debug('joining worker handler')
        if threading.current_thread() is not worker_handler:
            worker_handler.join()

        # patch ---------------------------------------------------------------
        print('_terminate_pool barrier waiting')  # DEBUG
        self._barrier.wait()  # <- blocks until all processes have called wait()
        print('_terminate_pool barrier crossed')  # DEBUG
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Terminate workers which haven't already finished.
        if pool and hasattr(pool[0], 'terminate'):
            util.debug('terminating workers')
            for p in pool:
                if p.exitcode is None:
                    p.terminate()

        util.debug('joining task handler')
        if threading.current_thread() is not task_handler:
            task_handler.join()

        util.debug('joining result handler')
        if threading.current_thread() is not result_handler:
            result_handler.join()

        if pool and hasattr(pool[0], 'terminate'):
            util.debug('joining pool workers')
            for p in pool:
                if p.is_alive():
                    # worker has not yet exited
                    util.debug('cleaning up worker %d' % p.pid)
                    p.join()
```

Now, in your main module you only have to switch `Pool` for `PatientPool` and pass the needed `at_exit`-arguments. For simplicity my exit-handler appends the local_score to a toml-file. Note that `local_score` needs to be a global variable so the exit-handler can have access to it.

```
import os
from functools import wraps
# from multiprocessing import log_to_stderr, set_start_method
# import logging
import toml
from at_exit_pool import register_at_exit, PatientPool


local_score = {
    "hits": 0,
    "misses": 0
}


def memoize(func):

    cache = {}

    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args):
        cache_key = str(args)  # ~14% faster than pickle.dumps(args)
        if cache_key not in cache:
            local_score["misses"] += 1
            cache[cache_key] = func(*args)
        else:
            local_score["hits"] += 1
        return cache[cache_key]

    return wrap


@memoize
def foo(x):
    for _ in range(int(x)):
        x - 1
    return x


def dump_score(pathfile):
    with open(pathfile, 'a') as fh:
        toml.dump({str(os.getpid()): local_score}, fh)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # set_start_method('spawn')
    # logger = log_to_stderr()
    # logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    PATHFILE = 'score.toml'
    N_WORKERS = 4

    arguments = [10e6 + i for i in range(10)] * 5
    # print(arguments[:10])

    with PatientPool(at_exit=dump_score, at_exit_args=(PATHFILE,),
                     processes=N_WORKERS) as pool:

        results = pool.map(foo, arguments, chunksize=3)
        # print(results[:10])
```

A run of this example would produce a terminal output like this, where "_terminate_pool barrier crossed" will always be executed last, while the flow before this line may vary:

```
555 barrier waiting
_terminate_pool barrier waiting
554 barrier waiting
556 barrier waiting
557 barrier waiting
_terminate_pool barrier crossed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The toml-file with the scores for this run looks like this:

```
[555]
hits = 3
misses = 8
[554]
hits = 3
misses = 9
[556]
hits = 2
misses = 10
[557]
hits = 5
misses = 10
```